# Get image from gallery to set in imageview in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to get image from gallary to set in Imageview in fragment ? onActivityResult not called in fragment..this the code i wrote in fragment

```
img_user.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);


        }
    });


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if (data != null) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            img_user.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            cursor.close`enter code here`();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Try Again!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please provide more context. What is not working the way you expected?

Comment: startActivityForResult is work in Fragment @Niral

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in this way....in your main activity

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       //call super 
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     }
```

and inside your fragment

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                // ******** code for crop image
                i.putExtra("crop", "true");
                i.putExtra("aspectX", 100);
                i.putExtra("aspectY", 100);
                i.putExtra("outputX", 256);
                i.putExtra("outputY", 356);

                try {

                    i.putExtra("return-data", true);
                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(i, "Select Picture"), 0);
                }catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
```

and

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            try {
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap bitmap = bundle.getParcelable("data");
                img_user.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Works perfect for me

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same problem. Actually callback for `startActivityForResult()` is coming back to parent activity so you need to make
explicit call from fragment to `onActivityResult()` function as follows.

In Parent Activity class, override the `onActivityResult()` method and even override the same in Fragment Class and call as the following code.

In Parent Class:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

In Child Class:
That Extends fragment perform your logic for image setting on imageview.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {



        if (data != null) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);

                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                 String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

                cursor.close();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Try Again!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

Comment: This code help for me.I hope it will solve your problem. i took help from from                                   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment

Answer (score 1):

Please find the following code, it will work. Add this in your fragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

//Your stuff

}
```

Comment: @ViktorYakunin why, can you tell me?

Comment: in the original question it is stated that this doesn't work. I faced this issue before, you have to pass request code > 0, if it didn't help, find your fragment in Activity and explicitly call onActivityResult.

Comment: I have tested this code in show many projects, and its working fine.