# How to get image from Gallery as a file and also set it in ImageView in Fragments Android

Tags: android, image, fragment, gallery

I want to get an image from gallery and set it on an ImageView in fragments. I also want to upload the image to my API backend as a file in fragments, so it needs to be in a format that allows me to upload the file. This is how it looks like in Postman.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewIiJ.png)

The *addCover_btn* allows me to open the gallery and select an image, but it crashes as soon as I select the image.

FragmentWriting.java

```
public class FragmentWriting extends Fragment implements Serializable, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    ImageView imageView;
    Uri imageUri;

        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_writing, container, false);

            addCover_btn = rootView.findViewById(R.id.addCoverButton);

//            imageView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.short_image).setOnClickListener();

        addCover_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openGallery();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    // Getting image from gallery try 2.0
    private void openGallery() {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 100);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 100){
            imageUri = data.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }
```

[Here is a screenshot of the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbuQP.png)

Comment: "but it crashes as soon as I select the image" -- use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with the crash.

Comment: Can you please add a Logcat shapshot

Comment: @DheerajGupta I just did, please check.

Answer (score 0):

So, the method works differently when you are doing it in a fragment and not in an activity. [I solved it using the first answer on this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34155990/get-image-from-gallery-to-set-in-imageview-in-fragment)